# Which is Best .toJS() vs .toJSON() in immutable js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am new to React+Redux+Immutable js ,I am using toJS() to tranforming my Immutable Data structure to Native javascript form.But Recently I stumbleupon with this tweet

[Author of Immutable.Js](https://twitter.com/leeb/status/746733697093668864)

Tweet says .toJS() is very expensive So can i go with toJSON() 
https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/toJSON is it ok with perf issue

UPDATE

```
const initialState = fromJS({
   postArr:[]
});

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return{
            posts:state.allPosts.toJS()
        }
    };
```

Pls provide some example with my own Reducer

How can i iterate `this.props.posts` without using to.js()

Comment: well JS is for use programmatically and JSON is just a string. they're not the same

Comment: Ok what is Best alternative for .toJS Coz I am building Mobile focused website where perf matters

Comment: use toJS but only when you need it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From what I understand from [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/#converts-back-to-raw-javascript-objects-):

- `toJSON()` returns a shallowly copied version of the immutable object (not a JSON *string*, although the name might suggest otherwise), which should only be used to pass to `JSON.stringify()` (in other words: you shouldn't use it as a regular object in your code).
- `toJS()` returns a deeply copied version of the immutable object, which you can subsequently use/modify in your code. Because it's a deeply copied version, it's more expensive to generate.

Comment: Ok what will be the best Use case for toJS() if i have 100 items to iterate the LIST()

Comment: What's the purpose of the iteration? Immutable offers lots of methods that you can apply to immutable objects directly (see [Sequence Algorithms](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/asImmutable)).

Comment: Oh Sorry I had different understanding .So we could use Immutable js map to iterate no need of .toJS() right Correct Me if I am wrong

Comment: If you have a `Map`, you could iterate over it using `for (let entry of yourMap) { ... }` (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/%5BSymbol.iterator%5D)

Comment: I am sorry to disturb Could you Pls provide example for my own reducer I updated my Question

Comment: Your initial state has `postArr` but `mapStateToProps` is refering to `state.allPosts`? I don't know much about Redux, but can't you return `state` directly and iterate over it (I assume in JSX) with `{ this.props.postArr.map(...) }`?

Comment: Well, the adjectives "deep" and "shallow" only refer to those objects in an immutable structure that are still "simple" JavaScript objects or arrays (and that should not be there in the first place anyway...). All immutable Maps, Lists, Sets etc. *will* be copied into an independent JavaScript object structure (even when using `toJSON()`!) that *can* be modified without running into any danger of affecting the original immutable object.

Comment: @cars10 if they both get copied, what's the distinction between the two that makes `toJS` less performant than `toJSON`?

Comment: The "deep" copy (`toJS()`) will actually create a new *instance* of the "simple" JS-object for the target object structure, whereas the `toJSON()`will simply put a reference to the existing JS-object into the target object structure. This could make things in your "immutable" object vulnerable to changes. But it really depends on your use case, how relevant this is.

Comment: @cars10 thnx for the explanation :D